# Comparação de ID em elementos XML

Tags: php, xml

Estou fazendo uma verificação entre 2 `ids` de 2 elementos diferentes em `XML`, porém quando faço a comparação o resultado é sempre `false` mesmo que o `gettype` seja o mesmo resultado e o numero também seja o mesmo resultado.

Para realizar a verificação eu tenho 2 `loops`, um dentro do outro, o primeiro é o resultado da comparação de igualdade:

```
var_dump($filme->attributes()['id'] == $m->attributes()['id']);
```

E o segundo é a comparação dos tipos e dos `id's`:

```
echo get_class($filme->attributes()['id']) . ' ' .$filme->attributes()['id'] 
. ' --> ' . 
get_class($m->attributes()['id']) . ' ' . $m->attributes()['id'] . '<hr/>';
```

Abaixo a lista completa:

```
bool(false)
SimpleXMLElement 5794 --> SimpleXMLElement 5718

bool(false)
SimpleXMLElement 5794 --> SimpleXMLElement 5764

bool(false)
SimpleXMLElement 5794 --> SimpleXMLElement 5767

bool(false)
SimpleXMLElement 5794 --> SimpleXMLElement 5792

bool(false)
SimpleXMLElement 5794 --> SimpleXMLElement 5794

bool(false)
SimpleXMLElement 5794 --> SimpleXMLElement 6015

bool(false)
SimpleXMLElement 5794 --> SimpleXMLElement 6031

bool(false)
SimpleXMLElement 5794 --> SimpleXMLElement 6052
```

Note na quinta linha do resultado a cima que o resultado é o mesmo porém a verificação é `false`

```
bool(false)
SimpleXMLElement 5794 --> SimpleXMLElement 5794
```

Já realizei a verificação dos tipos e dos valores e continuo recebendo `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim não funciona?

```
var_dump((string)$filme->attributes()['id'] == (string)$m->attributes()['id']);
```

Comment: Pq funcionaria dessa forma? poderia explicar?

Comment: Porque a comparação entre dois objetos (SimpleXMLElement) pode considerar outros aspectos que não somente o valor que é representado... Fazendo o cast pro tipo string, a comparação fica restrito ao valor da tag...

Comment: de fato funcionou. eu havia tentado usar `(int)` mas o certo era `(integer)`.